# Find limit of expressions where the numerator contains natural logarithm of 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

find $\displaystyle \lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{\ln(5xy+1)}{5x^8y^3+5xy} \right)$ where $x, y > 0$

I haven't touched math for quite a while. Normally I would try to factorize the numerator and the denominator so the denominator doesn't approach 0 but for this particular problem, I don't know how to start. Thank you for all the help you can provide.

Comment: what have your tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I changed the question. I didn't mean to come up as lazy or anything. I just haven't done calculus for a couple years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{\ln (5xy+1)}{5x^8y^3 + 5xy}= \frac{\ln(5xy+1)}{5xy} \times \frac{1}{x^7y^2 +1}  $$

Consider the first and second factors as separate limits. For the first one , let $5xy=t$. Then you get $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} $$ which is a well-known limit. The second one can be calculated just by substituting the values.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution.